# Is it possible to update CoreData from NotificationServiceExtension?

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications

I need to save notification count for every room in CoreData when I get push notification.

I am sending simple notification with category and thread-id to be able to differentiate which room. By setting mutable_content=1 it is possible to fire willPresent even in the background, but I also need to fire it when app is exited.
Is it possible to update data CoreData in NotificationServiceExtension using contentHandler for Mutable Notifications?

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is impossible. Instead, AppGroup's UserDefaults was used to save dictionary of thread-id and counts. Then CoreData was updated on App Launch using that dictionary.
[This blog helped me to come up with this solution](https://medium.com/gits-apps-insight/processing-notification-data-using-notification-service-extension-6a2b5ea2da17)